# stuck trying to prove sublist of list

Tags: coq

i create sublist from list in this way:

```
Fixpoint sublist {X : Type} (n : nat) (m : nat) (lst : list X) : list X :=  
  match lst with
  | [] => []
  | h :: t => match m with
              | O => match n with 
                     | O => []
                     | S n' => h :: sublist n' O t
                     end
              
              | S m' => sublist n m' t
              end
  end.
```

i want to proof that if m is greater or equel to the length of the list, sublist n m list will return empty list:

```
Theorem sublist_list_after_m :  forall X : Type, forall n m : nat, forall lst :list X , 
  m <? (length lst) = false -> length (sublist n m lst) =? 0 = true.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct lst as [|h t].
   - simpl. reflexivity.
   - simpl. destruct n as [|n'].
     + simpl. reflexivity.
     + destruct m as [|m'].
       -- Admitted.
```

But I not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, a proof about a recursive function should include some form of induction.  Induction is usually implemented by tactics `induction` or `elim` (the latter is used a lot in the mathematical components library).  So I would expect that your proof will get much easier if you replace your first use of `destruct` by `induction` (adding a name in the introduction pattern for the induction hypothesis).

Also, I suggest loading the induction, replacing the first `intros` tactic by:

```
`intros X n m lst; revert n m.`
```

and then calling the `induction` tactic.

These are *rules of thumb*, I give them without even knowing whether the statement is provable or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof that uses induction and reorders the intros to make the induction hypothesis sufficiently general, just as @Yves suggested.

```
Proof.
intros X n m lst; revert n m.
induction lst; intros n m Hlen.
- reflexivity.
- destruct m. 
  exfalso; now simpl in Hlen.
  apply IHlst.
  apply Hlen.
Qed.
```